# Image not added to Gallery

Tags: android, uri, android-gallery

I have followed tutorials and Stackoverflow's questions without any success.

What I have to do is: **take a picture from Camera, save it and show it in the gallery.**

I don't know why with the following code, the image is not added to the gallery. The code doesn't give any error and I have checked with some `Log.i` that it is fully executed. But the problem remains: the picture is taken but not shown into the gallery.

Because of my code is really long, I report only the key parts in order to make the reading easier. I hope that it is clear enough.

```
File mFile = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "pic.jpg");
mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile)); // it saves the image
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(mFile);
getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, contentUri));
```

Comment: Do you have WRITE PERMISSION in your manifest??

Comment: Just FYI, 4 lines of code is not clear enough (at least for me). If I were you, I would add more related code and explain more. Some questions from my side: Where does the image come from, camera? What do you mean by image not added to gallery, you can't save the image? You can't save it or the image is saved but can't see in the Gallery app? etc.